# from proto2 debugString to json

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm new to protocol buffers, and I' m having some hard time parsing the human readable output from proto2 (DebugString function, ref [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated)) to a structured data.

In fact, at first, I tried to do this recursively and then i though about using the debugString() function that I can use. What I want is a simple structured output (json) that contain fieldnames and their values, but proto2 doesn't have a json output or coverter... (correct me if i' m wrong)  and I'm working with cpp

Is there any other way to do this work without manually handling it? Do you know any library that is doing that?

thank you

Comment: Do you have its `.proto` file?

Comment: This looks like an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what is your end goal? `DebugString` creates a "text proto" representation which *is* a structured representation. If you really do need JSON, there's a [`MessageToJsonString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.json_util#MessageToJsonString.details) which you can use.